# Some posts in Facebook event page cannot be “like” or “comment”

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I held an [event](http://www.facebook.com/events/102054579912365/) on our company's Facebook page. It is a fan contest that users will contribute their photos on our event page and we will select the winner based on times of "likes".

Most of the posts work great, but some of the submitted photos cannot be "Like", "Comment" or "Share" on the wall. (These photos can be shared or like after click in). Is there any configuration I can do or I can ask the submitter to fix in order to solve this issues?

[image]

Comment: I seem to remember encountering something like this that had to do with privacy settings on the photos, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One post is a photo wall post as seen with the

> Facebook user > Astrophotography Contest  Deep Space & Planet

The other is a photo tag with other users that may or may not be invited to the event. I am guessing the users who are tagged have privacy settings that affect it.